# Le rôle de « du » lorsqu'il est suivi d'une date

Tags: grammaire, articles, prépositions, contractions

Soit les phrases suivantes avec la date.

- Arrêté **du** 20 mai 2014.
- Loi **du** …
- Décret **du** …
- Jugement **du** …
- Période **du** …
- Soins **du** …

Questions :

1. Est-ce que *du* est un article partitif dans ces phrases?
2. C'est quoi le rôle de *du* dans ces phrases. Est-ce qu'il y a un mot
   technique qu'on puisse utiliser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le mot *du* est la contraction de deux mots : *de* + *le*. Il peut s'agir de l'article partitif *de/du/de la/de l'/des*, ou bien de la préposition *de* suivie de l'article défini *le*.

Dans tous les exemples que tu cites, *du* est la préposition plus l'article. Orthographiquement, il n'y a qu'un mot, mais grammaticalement, il y en a deux, une préposition et un article.

Il peut y avoir autre chose qu'une date après *du*, ce peut être n'importe quel groupe nominal autour d'un nom masculin singulier qui se trouve être introduit par la préposition *de*.

Answer (score 5):

**de le** se contracte effectivement en **du** quand *le* est un article :

> Je viens **du** salon (Je viens *de le* salon).

et non quand il est pronom, comme dans

> Je viens **de le** faire. (Je viens de faire *quelque chose*.)

Cependant, il n'y a pas de lien entre la contraction de l'article et l'expression des dates. On aurait tout aussi bien *une loi du Maroc*, *la loi du 7 juillet 1977*, ou *la loi du plus fort*.

Comment: Et – ironie! – la date fantaisiste que j'ai prise en exemple... ne l'est [pas](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000338793). Pour le coup, elle serait même d'actualité.

Answer (score 1):

1. Non
2. C'est un article contracté (il remplace *de le*)

Comment: *Du* n'est pas (ici) un article contracté, c'est une préposition contractée avec un article.

Comment: @Gilles, c'est la terminologie utilisée par Grevisse dans mon édition du Bon Usage.

Comment: @Unfrancophone. Dans mon édition du *Bon usage* (1975), **de** (qui peut se modifier s'il est placé devant certains articles), est bien classé parmi les prépositions pour cet emploi. Voir « Emploi de certaines prépositions », « La préposition *de* marque des rapports variés ;  elle peut exprimer notamment :[...]  Des rapports divers présentant une certaine analogie avec le rapport d'appartenance... »

Comment: @Laure, _de_ est bien une préposition, c'est _du_, _des_, _au_, _aux_ et _ès_ qui sont des articles contractés dans mon édition.